# How to play Crysis 2 in Third Person view mode

Tags: pc, crysis-2

In "Saves" directory of Crysis 2, I saw a file named "actionmaps.xml" which says

```
  <action name="flymode" onPress="1" noModifiers="1">
   <key name="f3"/>
  </action>
  <action name="godmode" onPress="1" noModifiers="1">
   <key name="f4"/>
  </action>
  <action name="ulammo" onPress="1" noModifiers="1">
   <key name="np_2"/>
  </action>
  <action name="debug" onPress="1">
   <key name="7"/>
  </action>
  <action name="thirdperson" onPress="1" noModifiers="1">
   <key name="f1"/>
  </action>
```

How do I play in third person view mode? Pressing F1 does nothing.

Answer (score 2):

You need to enable the **Developer Mode** in order to be able to use these commands.

> To enable the developer mode, you need to start the game with the
>   "`-devmode`" command line parameter (either edit the start menu shortcut
>   or create a batch file containing "`Crysis2.exe -devmode`". When the
>   developer mode is enabled, you'll be able to use the following key
>   bindings:
>
> - F1: toggles between first and third person view
> - F2: teleports you to the next checkpoint
> - F3: switches between fly mode, noclip mode, and back to normal
> - F10: removes many textures and shows polygons
> - Num1: gives quite a few weapons (notably the JAW and L-TAG) and
>     refills ammunition
>
> Update: After some research it has been found out that the "`-devmode`"
>   cannot be used after patching the game to version 1.2. However, there
>   might be ways to bypass this through using scripts and/or similar.

Source: [Wiki4Games](http://www.wiki4games.com/Crysis_2#Cheats)

Comment: just having a bit of having the same issue but a bit complex,i created a Batch file under "C:\Program Files (x86)\Electronic Arts\Crytek\Crysis 2\bin32" but when i tried to open it up and used the key combination i was unable to switch to third person mode..
i even tried creating a Xml file in saved file directory with key combinations in it..but that file content changes every time i get in game still im unable to change the views any solution please reply as soon as you can..can wait to play this game